# Run a sed search and replace inside perl

Tags: sed, perl

I am trying to test the code snippet below for a bigger script that I am writing. However, I can't get the search working with parentheses and variables.

Appreciate any help someone can give me.

Code snippet:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file="test4.html";
$Search="Help (Test)";
$Replace="Testing";

print "/usr/bin/sed -i cb 's/$Search/$Replace/g' $file\n";
`/usr/bin/sed -i cb 's/$Search/$Replace/g' $file`;
```

Thanks,

Ash

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to provide sample input, desired output, and actual output so that contributors can better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why are you calling sed from perl ? One of perl's biggest strengths is regular expressions. Doing it in perl itself is faster, easier and safer.

Comment: Besides that it seems not to make any sense to generate `sed` calls in `perl`: `perl` is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to run a command in a child process and wait for its termination in `perl` is `system "cmd", "arg1", "arg2",...`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file="test4.html";
$Search="Help (Test)";
$Replace="Testing";

print "/usr/bin/sed -icb -e 's/$Search/$Replace/g' -- $file\n";
system "/usr/bin/sed", "-icb", "-e", "s/$Search/$Replace/g", "--", $file;
```

(error checking left as an exercise, see `perldoc -f system` for details)

Note that `-i` is not a standard `sed` option. The few implementations that support it (yours must be the FreeBSD one as you've separated the `cb` backup extension from `-i`) have actually copied it from `perl`! It does feel a bit silly to be calling `sed` from `perl` here.

Looking at your approach:

The `` `...` `` operator itself is reminiscent of the equivalent `` `...` `` shell operator. In `perl`, what's inside is evaluated as if inside double quoted, in that `$var`, `@var`... perl variables are expanded, and a shell is started with `-c` and the resulting string as arguments and with its stdout redirected to a pipe.

The shell interprets that argument as code in the shell syntax. Perl reads the output of that inline shell script from the other end of the pipe and that makes up the expansion of `` `...` ``. Same as in shell command substitution except that there's is no stripping of zero bytes or of trailing newlines.

`sed -i` produces no output, so it's pointless to try and capture its output with `` `...` `` here.

Now in your case, the code that `sh` is asked to interpret is:

```
/usr/bin/sed -i cb 's/Help (Test)/Testing/g' test4.html
```

That should work fine on FreeBSD or macOS at least. If `$file` had been `test$(reboot).html`, that would have been worse though.

Here, because you have the contents of variables that end up interpreted as code in an interpreter (here `sh`), you have a potential arbitrary command injection vulnerability.

In the `system` approach, we remove `sh`, so that particular vulnerability is removed. However `sed` is also an interpreter of some language. That language is not as omnipotent as that of `sh`, but for instance `sed` can write to arbitrary files with its `w` command. The GNU implementation (which you don't seem to be using) can run arbitrary commands as well.

So you still potentially have a code injection vulnerability in the case of `$Search` or `$Replace` coming from an external source.

If that's the case, you'd need to make sure your properly sanitise those values before running `sed`. See for instance: [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059)